# Python Selenium Upload a file via AutoIT

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, autoit

I am trying AutoIT first time to upload `.xlsx` file in python. It's not text box so I can not use `sendkey` method.
This is AutoIT script:

```
import autoit
WinWaitActive("File Upload")
Send("C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\bdd\data\Abc- Remove EMail addressfinal .xlsx")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Call the `autoIt.exe` file in python

```
import os

def selectPlusDataFile(self):
    self.elementClick(self._plusdataFile, locatorType='xpath')
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Opening.....")
        os.system('C:\\Users\\abc\\Documents\\AutoIT\\FileUpload5.exe')
```

When I execute `py.test` it's giving me error dialogbox.

What could be missing?
[Upload file screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whroE.png)

I have tried different scripts.

1.

```
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1","C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\bdd\data\Abc - Remove EMail addressfinal .xlsx")
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

2. 

```
WinWaitActive("Open")
ControlSetText("Open", "", "ComboBox1", "C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\bdd\data\Abc - Remove EMail addressfinal .xlsx")
ControlClick("Open", "", "Button1")
```

3. 

```
WinWaitActive("Open")
Send("C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\bdd\data\Abc - Remove EMail addressfinal .xlsx")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

4. 

```
import autoit
autoit.win_active("Open")
autoit.control_set_text("Open","Edit1",r"C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\bdd\data\Abc - Remove EMail addressfinal .xlsx")
autoit.control_send("Open","Edit1","{ENTER}")
```

5. 

```
import autoit
autoit.win_wait("[CLASS:#32770;TITLE:Open]", 60)
autoit.control_send("[CLASS:#32770;TITLE:Open]", "Edit1", os.path.join(mpath,"C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\bdd\data\Abc - Remove EMail addressfinal .xlsx"))
autoit.control_click("[CLASS:#32770;TITLE:Open]", "Button1")
```

6:

```
import autoit
WinWaitActive("File Upload")
Send("C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\bdd\data\Abc - Remove EMail addressfinal .xlsx")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML.